# Why is this column not found in this SQL table, when the table was defined with it included?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create two SQLite databases through python 3.8 to store user information. I have two scripts defining the databases and one to fill it with test data.  The first database works fine. It is defined by the script create_logindb.py:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import Column, Date, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref
import bcrypt

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///upa.db', echo=True)
Base = declarative_base()

def create_hashed_password(plain_text_password):
    # Hash a password for the first time
    #   (Using bcrypt, the salt is saved into the hash itself)
    return bcrypt.hashpw(plain_text_password.encode('utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt()).decode('utf8')

def check_hashed_password(plain_text_password, hashed_password):
    # Check hashed password. Using bcrypt, the salt is saved into the hash itself
    return bcrypt.checkpw(plain_text_password.encode('utf-8'), hashed_password.encode('utf-8'))


########################################################################
class User(Base):
    """"""

    def __init__(self, username, password, app_location):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.app_location = app_location

        
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String)
    password = Column(String)
    app_location = Column(String)
#----------------------------------------------------------------------

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

I have a similar database defined with create_redirectauthdb:

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:////Users/rpfhome/Documents/POS II/log in/ra.db', echo=True)
Base = declarative_base()



########################################################################
class Redirected_User(Base):
    """"""

    def __init__(self, username, hash_time, hash_value,user_ip,user_store):
        self.username = username
        self.hash_time = hash_time
        self.hash_value  = hash_value
        self.user_ip = user_ip#ip of user
        self.user_store = user_store#location of user data
        
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String)
    hash_time = Column(String)
    hash_value = Column(String)
    user_ip = Column(String)
    user_store = Column(String)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

# create tables
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

and I am creating the test accounts with:

```
import datetime
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from create_logindb import *
from create_redirectauthdb import *
import bcrypt
import random
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///upa.db', echo=True)

# def create_hashed_password(plain_text_password):
#     # Hash a password for the first time
#     #   (Using bcrypt, the salt is saved into the hash itself)
#     return bcrypt.hashpw(plain_text_password.encode('utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt())


# create a Session
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

user = User("admin", create_hashed_password("password"), 'localhost:8000')
session.add(user)

user = User("python", create_hashed_password("python"), 'localhost:8001')
session.add(user)

user = User("jumpiness", create_hashed_password("python"),'localhost:8002')
session.add(user)

# commit the record the database
session.commit()

engine2 = create_engine('sqlite:////Users/rpfhome/Documents/POS II/log in/ra.db', echo=True)
Session2 = sessionmaker(bind=engine2)
session2 = Session()


user = Redirected_User("admin", 'uninitialized_datetime', str('%032x' % random.getrandbits(128)), '0.0.0.0','$Home/Documents/POS II/log in/')
session2.add(user)

user = Redirected_User("python", 'uninitialized_datetime', str('%032x' % random.getrandbits(128)), '0.0.0.0','$Home/Documents/POS II/log in/')
session2.add(user)

user = Redirected_User("jumpiness", 'uninitialized_datetime', str('%032x' % random.getrandbits(128)), '0.0.0.0','$Home/Documents/POS II/log in/')
session2.add(user)

# commit the record the database
session2.commit()
```

This is just a toy example I'm using to get started. The first database, upa.db, is created and populated fine. Trying to create the second database creates the error:

```
...
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) table users has no column named hash_time
[SQL: INSERT INTO users (username, hash_time, hash_value, user_ip, user_store) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('admin', 'uninitialized_datetime', '287cac9fcc2ab4760d8318190f182630', '0.0.0.0', '$Home/Documents/POS II/log in/')]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
```

The background page for the error doesn't seem very helpful in this case.  I was wondering why It's saying there's no column named hash_time when the database was defined with that column included. I thought this might have to do with the fact that both databases include a table named "users" so I renamed the table "users2" in the script that defines the database but then got an error that there is no tables called users2 when running the script that fills it with example data. This also doesn't make much sense to me. I've also tried changing all instances of Base to Base2 in the second script but this seems to have no effect. Why does the database in the script to fill it with example data not seem to match the structure of the database defined in the script that creates it?

Comment: Did you connect to the second DB directly to check if created structure was correct ? (to narrow down the issue - if the root cause is in the creation process)

Comment: I've tested ra database creation and inserts. It works fine for me. Maybe state of DB was messed in the beginning.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried adding ```q=engine2.execute('pragma table_info(users)').fetchall()
for i in q:
    print(q)
    print('\n')``` to the script that populates the table before adding a user and got the result: `[(0, 'id', 'INTEGER', 1, None, 1), (1, 'username', 'VARCHAR', 0, None, 0), (2, 'hash_time', 'VARCHAR', 0, None, 0), (3, 'hash_value', 'VARCHAR', 0, None, 0), (4, 'user_ip', 'VARCHAR', 0, None, 0), (5, 'user_store', 'VARCHAR', 0, None, 0)] `. This seems right but perhaps I'm not understanding it correctly

Comment: I also connected to the database directly with SQLite3 and performed the query: ```schema users
CREATE TABLE users (
 id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
 username VARCHAR, 
 hash_time VARCHAR, 
 hash_value VARCHAR, 
 user_ip VARCHAR, 
 user_store VARCHAR, 
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);```

Comment: `session2` is created from `Session()` instead of `Session2()` (Line 34)!

Comment: Thanks! That solves it. I missed this at first because I was thinking of the session object imported from flask used in a subsequent script and forgetting that I. This script it’s something else

Answer (score 0):

As @rfkortekaas pointed out, it was a simple bug.  session2 was created from Session() for the first database and wouldn't work on the second.